# On Linux: We see following: Physical, Real, Swap, Virtual Memory - Which should we consider for sizing?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual, ram

We use a Tool (Whats Up Gold) to monitor memory usage on a Linux Box.
We see Memory usage (graphs) related to:

Physical, Real, Swap, Virtual Memory and ALL Memory (*which is a average of all these*).

```
'The ALL' Memory graphs show low memory usage of about: 10%. 
But Physical memory shows as 95% used.
Swap memory shows as 2% used.
```

So, do i need more memory on this Linux Box? 
In other words should i go by:

- ALL Memory graph(which says memory situation is good) OR
- Physical Memory Graph (which says memory situation is bad).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Real and Physical**

Physical memory is the amount of DRAM which is currently used. Real memory shows how much your applications are using system DRAM memory. It is roughly lower than physical memory. Linux system caches some of disk data. This caching is the difference between physical and real memory. Actually, when you have free memory Linux goes to use it for caching. Do not worry, as your applications demand memory they gonna get the cached space back.

**Swap and Virtual**

Swap is additional space to your actual DRAM. This space is borrowed from disk space and once you application fill-out entire DRAM, Linux transfers some unused memory to swap to let all application stay alive. Total of swap and physical memory is the virtual memory.

**Do you need extra memory?**

In answer to your question, you need to check real memory. If your real memory is full, you need to get some RAM. Use `free` command to check the amount of actual free memory. For example on my system `free` says:

```
$ free
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:      16324640    9314120    7010520          0     433096    8066048
    -/+ buffers/cache:     814976   15509664
    Swap:      2047992          0    2047992
```

You need to check buffer/cache section. As shown above, there are real 15 GB free DRAM (second line) on my system. Check this on your system and find out whether you need more memory or not. The lines represent physical, real, and swap memory, respectively.

Comment: Thanks ahmad, that helps. I guess you mean 15 GB and not 1.5GB above. So i guess PHYSICAL Memory graphs are drawn using data from First Line (of free memory command result). But What about REAL Memory graph - does the second line (of -/+ buffers/cache) - represent that?

Comment: You are all right! The lines represent physical, real, and swap respectively.

Comment: If that's the case, then there is 7GB of physics and 15GB of real memory on your computer? How can that be? Is physical the second line?

Comment: Physical memory is reported in the first line of `free`'s output. Total physical memory is 16GB. At this snapshot, 7GB out of 16GB are free. Information is added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## free -m

as for free tool analisys about memory lack in linux i have some opinion proved by experiments (practice)

```
~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2000         164         144        1605        1691         103
```

you should summarize 'used'+'shared' and compare with 'total'

other columns are useless just confuse and nothing more

i would say

```
[ total - (used + shared ) ] should be always at least > 200 MB
```

also you can get almost the same number if you check  MemAvailable in meminfo :

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemAvailable:     107304 kB
```

MemAvailable - is how much memory linux thinks right now is really free before active swapping happens.
so  now  you can consume 107304 kB maximum. if you
consume more big swappening starts happening.

MemAvailable also is in good correlation with real practice.