# Get server memory usages on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2, centos

We are running our J2EE application on *Amazon EC2* instance server which is an *m1.large* instance 
having configuration as

```
Instance Family    
Instance Type   Processor   Arch        vCPU    ECU Memory (GiB)    Instance Storage (GB)   EBS-optimized Available Network Performance

General     purpose     m1.large    64-bit  2   4   7.5 2 x 420 Yes     Moderate
```

now when I check memory usages of my server I found that free memory is 0 as shown below

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:             7          6          0          0          0          5
-/+ buffers/cache:          1          5
Swap:            0          0          0
```

After investigating bit on server I got following details...

```
Process Name    Number of processes Memory usage per process    Total memory usage 
java            2           523.379 MB          1046.76 MB
httpd           24          3.47965 MB          83.5117 MB
memcached       1           13.7227 MB          13.7227 MB
sshd            3           2.91016 MB          8.73047 MB
rsyslogd        1           5.51953 MB          5.51953 MB
pickup          1           3.25781 MB          3.25781 MB
udevd           2           1.24805 MB          2.49609 MB
master          1           2.84375 MB          2.84375 MB
qmgr            1           2.77734 MB          2.77734 MB
crond           1           1.30078 MB          1.30078 MB
auditd          1           0.789062 MB         0.789062 MB
```

which having total usages around ***1 .5 GB*** now I can not understand where this ***5.33 GB*** is going to used
and how can I find the details about it can someone help me about this

***NOTE:*** we are running two tomcat on same server for QA and Production

**Apatche** : *2*

**Tomcat Version** : *7 (for Both)*

**Memcached** : for better performance

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output of `free` command shows above, 5 GB of data is cached. This is a part of Hard Disk which is cached in RAM. Linux will free the memory as the applications need them. More information is available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917179/on-linux-we-see-following-physical-real-swap-virtual-memory-which-should). Trust linux, he knows the memory management and will free the cached space, as an application needs RAM.

Comment: thanks for referred answer which gives me clearer picture..

Comment: it means that I have 5GB of free memory on my server right ? thus I don't need extra memory ...

Comment: yes. It means now you have 5GB used as `disk cache` which will be freed immediately as an application needs it. So you do not need to buy extra RAM now.

Answer (score 2):

usaully the kernel reserves all the memory and start assigning to application based on request and demand. so all the remaining memory is being assigned buffers and cache, which is claimable by kernel at any given time to get more information about memory utilization `cat /proc/meminfo`

Comment: thanks for your reply... you mean that remaining memory is used by kernel right ?

Comment: it is aloocated by kernel as buffers and reclaimable caches

Comment: ok so its consider as used memory which is actually not used right ..?

Comment: true and you can find it under cached when you issue Free command